# Initilaizing stripe promise in react with connected account id

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am building an integration of stripe issuing, and I want to initiate stripe promise with a connected account id inorder to use createEphemeralKeyNonce, the account id is stored in firestore (firebase database).
I am initializing it in the App so I can pass it to Elements provider .

const stripePromise = loadStripe(publishableKey, {
stripeAccount: "",
});

Here is the Element provider

```
  <Router>
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <Navbar />

    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/payment" element={<Payment />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/cards" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path="/cards" element={<Cards />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </Elements>
</Router>
```

the problem is the stripeAccountId is coming from the database in useEffect, so it's async .

I tried to use it in a use effect , useMemo , useCallback , but no one worked , maybe I am missing something

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you need help with? You have the correct structure for initializing Stripe.js using the `stripeAccount` option, but where you get that value from, and when, will be something specific to your integration. You will need to defer calling `loadStripe` until you have that value.

Comment: I am getting the accountId from firestore , so for that I used useMemo useCallback .. etc  with accoundI in the dependency array   so the loadStripe will renitialize with accountId   .  but it seems that this cant work , because when first stripePromise get initialized with only  accountid as empty string , this cause an error

Comment: I get this error   react-stripe.umd.js:313 Uncaught Error: Invalid prop `stripe` supplied to `Elements`. We recommend using the `loadStripe` utility from `@stripe/stripe-js`. Se

Comment: Please show snippets of your code where you set up the `Elements` provider -- that errors sounds like there is something wrong there.

Comment: @NolanH I have updated the question with the code snnipet

Comment: @NolanH the issue is that when stripe promise first get initialized there is no account id , how can i make it wait for it ? I tried the above solution but didn't work . probably I am missing something

Comment: If you re-initialize Stripe.js (via loadStripe) with a connected account ID, you'll need to remount the Elements provider with the new stripe promise -- the prop cannot be updated after the initial promise resolves. You can force this for example by setting a React `key` prop on the Elements provider that concatenates the account id to force react to re-mount if that changes.

Comment: eg: `<Elements key={\`elements-key-${stripeAccountId}\`} stripe={stripePromise}>`

Comment: Regarding your (now deleted) question about whether to use an API or write the functionality yourself, readers will find that hard to answer because they don't know the details of the project. In general I'd say that creating appointments and handling date information in databases is fairly simple stuff, and I'd suggest just implementing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @halfer , I appreciate your help !